# File upload issue in Asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I added HTML input type file After I run the project and click to the input file for choosing my file. When I choose file and click OK after Stopped my project.
What is the problem?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "User", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
                {
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <div class="profile_img">
                            <div id="crop-avatar">
                                <img class="img-responsive avatar-view" width="250" height="150" src="~/Styles/images/@Model.User.Image" alt="Avatar" title="Change the avatar">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="file" name="file" id="file1" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-8 form-horizontal form-label-left">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.User.FirstName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" })
                            <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.User.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.User.LastName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" })
                            <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.User.LastName, new { @class = "form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.User.MiddleName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" })
                            <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.User.MiddleName, new { @class = "form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.User.UserName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" })
                            <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.User.UserName, new { @class = "form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.User.Email, new { @class = "control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" })
                            <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.User.Email, new { @class = "form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.User.Phone, new { @class = "control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" })
                            <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.User.Phone, new { @class = "form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.User.RoleId, new { @class = "control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" })
                            <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.User.RoleId, new SelectList(Model.Roles, "Id", "RoleName"), htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12", id = "roles" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.User.Note, new { @class = "control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" })
                            <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.User.Note, new { @class = "form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" , style = "min-height:100px !important" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.User.Id)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.User.CreateDate)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.User.Status)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.User.Password)
                    <div class="col-sm-12 text-center" style="padding-bottom:3px">
                        <button class="btn btn-default">Yadda Saxla</button>
                        <a href="@Url.Action("Index","User")" class="btn btn-default">İmtina</a>
                    </div>
                }
```

**UserController:**

```
 public ActionResult Update(int userId)
    {
        UserViewModel employeeViewModel = new UserViewModel
        {
            User = _userService.GetUser(userId),
            Roles = _userService.GetRoles()
        };
        return View(employeeViewModel);
    }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Update(UserViewModel userViewModel)
        {
            User user = new User();
            user.Id = userViewModel.User.Id;
            user.RoleId = userViewModel.User.RoleId;
            user.UserName = userViewModel.User.UserName;
            user.FirstName = userViewModel.User.FirstName;
            user.LastName = userViewModel.User.LastName;
            user.MiddleName = userViewModel.User.MiddleName;
            user.Email = userViewModel.User.Email;
            user.Phone = userViewModel.User.Phone;
            user.Note = userViewModel.User.Note;
            user.Status = userViewModel.User.Status;
            if (userViewModel.User.Id == 0) user.CreateDate = DateTime.Now;
            else user.CreateDate = userViewModel.User.CreateDate;
            _userService.UpdateEmployee(user);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Can do reference issue from Visual Studio?
Because when I remove

```
  <input type="file" name="file" id="file1" />
```

This section project worked good.
I think the problem is in another place that is not in the code
I already added `multipart/form-data` for File upload..
Please help me to fix this error..

Comment: Can you show the code for the Update action in the User controller

Comment: Where is your submit button? Do you receive any errors within Visual Studio?

Comment: @bsod_ Not, I cannot receive any error